# appendix is not showing

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, pdftex, miktex

i referred to some question in this website to know how can i make the appendix. i found the code required to make the appendix but when i tried to run it, it does not show any results.

please have a look at the belwo code and please let me know why i am not getting the appendix

**code**

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{atbegshi,picture}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\allsectionsfont{\centering}
\author{Amr}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}

\begin{document}

\begin{appendices}
\chapter{Consectetur adipiscing elit}
\chapter{Mauris euismod}
\end{appendices}
...
...
\end{document}
```

Comment: do you _really_ use all those packages or need an absolute path in your `\graphicspath` ? and you _must_ get an error from two `\documentclass` comamnds !!!!

Comment: You have two `\documentclass` (`article` does not support `\chapter`), the `appendix` package is loaded twice with different options each time.  `graphicx`, `titlesec` and `babel` are also unnecessarily loaded twice.  Finally the code has no `\end{document}`

Comment: you get the errors `! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package appendix.` and `! LaTeX Error: Two \documentclass or \documentstyle commands`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle no i do not get that error..the code is compile correctly but the appendix never shows up

Comment: @DaiBowen i removed the duplicate packages but still the appendix is not showing

Comment: You still have two `\documentclass` commands, as David Carlisle said this will give an error.  Remove the second and change the first from `article` to `report` (you cannot use `article` if you wish to continue using `\chapter`).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was caused by the presence of multiple \documentclass commands, reported in the comments, and is unlikely to help future visitors.

Comment: @DaiBowen i removed the the packages as u suggested but still the appendix is not showing and i do not recive any errors

Comment: you have changed the code.  now it is working when i run it.  titles appear for two appendices.

Comment: @Elpharaoh the current code runs and compiles fine.  If it's not compiling then there's probably something outside of the document (MiKTeX installing packages on the fly maybe?) going wrong.

Comment: yes you must have got those errors from the code as posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This* cleaned code compiles. I think it's not wise to load both `titlesec` and `sectsty`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[english]{babel}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{kpfonts}
%\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{atbegshi,picture}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\allsectionsfont{\centering}
\graphicspath{ {E:/Amr/private/MasterThesis2016/reports/thesisDoc/latex/images/} }
\author{Amr}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[titletoc, toc, page]{appendix}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}

\begin{document}

\begin{appendices}
\chapter{Consectetur adipiscing elit}
\chapter{Mauris euismod}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Comment: i tried your code but still the appendix is not showing!!!!

Comment: This code and nothing else? You have a blank document?

Comment: no every thing is appearing on he doc except the appendix

Comment: Well, there's something else in your code which is responsible for it. Could you post a *minimal* code reproducing the problem?